# How can I stop Applescript from comparing strings to numbers?

Tags: string, applescript

So I just found out that strings can be compared to each other in Applescript like this:

```applescript
"hello world" > "abc"
```

Returns:

```
true
```

However, you can also compare strings to numbers. The string will, however always be greater:

```applescript
"a" = 10 ^ 308 -- Close to infinity
```

Returns:

```
false
```

Is there a way to only compare numbers without using `try`- and `on error`-statements?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of your exercises is incomprehensible. It is not clear
what is the use? AppleScript is written exactly the way the developers wanted it to be. For example, they thought: why not compare a string to a number. You can't (and it's good that you can't) change the behavior of AppleScript's logical operations. But you can write your "smart equivalents" to them. And use them.

```
on isNumbersEqual(x, y)
    tell {real, integer}
        if x's class is not in it then error "LEFT OPERAND ISN'T NUMBER"
        if y's class is not in it then error "RIGHT OPERAND ISN'T NUMBER"
    end tell
    x = y
end isNumbersEqual

-- isNumbersEqual("1", 10 ^ 308) --> ERROR!!
isNumbersEqual(1, 10 ^ 308) --> false
```

**Note**: Unlike other programming languages, AppleScript does not throw an error when comparing strings to numbers. Instead, it implicitly coerces the number to a string to perform a legitimate comparison. You can check my statement:

```
("1" > 10 ^ 308) is ("1" > (10 ^ 308 as string)) --> true
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way around this is to check for the class of the variable or string you are passing:

```applescript
set x to "This is my innocent string"
if x > 0 and class of x ≠ string then --do stuff here.
```

Comment: How do you do the "not equal"?

Comment: @Martin Packer. You can type "≠" by pressing "=" key and Option key together.